# Wildcard index search result problem. I can't fetch what I want

Tags: mongodb

I've an instance of MongoDB with a lot of data in it and somebody trying to make search easier create a Wildcard Index but when I use .find() function I only got results when I use a complete sentence.

For example:

If I'm trying to find "Netherlands" but I only write "Neth" nothing happens. I want to make this kind of querys like when we use a Wildcard in SQL.

This is an example of what I'm doing:

db.getCollection('transaction').find({$text: {$search: "Neth"}},  {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})

Comment: Use regexp. $text is for text search. Learn the difference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#index-feature-text

Comment: It doesn't work. The field that I want to get is a Nested Object inside the document... Example: 
{data: 
    {
        Location: 
            {
                City:
                Country:
            }
    }
}

And so on...

Comment: How it is a problem? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation let you query any subdocument

Comment: Thank you Alex. It works now